# Como ejecutar 2 stores procedures al mismo tiempo?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Buen Dia quisiera saber como puedo ejecutar estos dos stores procedures al mismo tiempo

```
 exec msdb.dbo.rds_download_from_s3
 @s3_arn_of_file='',
 @rds_file_path='',
 @overwrite_file=1;

EXEC SPI_Archivos ''
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar ,Gracias de antemano

Comment: en el mismo momento exacto, probablemente es imposible. Si quieres que corran en paralelo simplemente ejecútalos en ventanas distintas

Comment: @Lamak entiendo pero lo que busco es correrlos en conjunto

Comment: no entiendo bien, para correrlos paralelamente la única forma es en procesos diferentes. Esa es la única opción